# Apache 2.2 User Permissions / Public access folder

Tags: apache-2.2, user-permissions

website.com:8080 is set to require a password.  However, I need website.com:8080/public to be accessible to anyone.

I found this example with Apache 2.3 which is exactly what I want, but I'm using 2.2 and AuthType None is not supported.

```
<Directory /www/docs>
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName Documents
   AuthBasicProvider file
   AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
   Require valid-user
</Directory>
<Directory /www/docs/public>
   AuthType None
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Directory /www/docs/public>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
  Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

The "Satisfy any" means that the "Allow from all" will be sufficient, even without the "Require valid-user" being satisfied.

Comment: That works, but I did have to add:LoadModule authz_host_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_host.so

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory /www/docs/public>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```